# jQuery: refactoring lazy code

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I've written a function like so which toggles elements on and off:

```
  // category filter
  $('.category-filter').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('data-category');
    $('.category-filter').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data-category').indexOf(category) >= 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success').fadeIn('fast');
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-default').fadeIn('fast');
          $('.article_container').each(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') })
          $('.category-filter').each(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') })
        })
      }
    })
    $('.article_container').each(function() {
      if (!($(this).attr('data-categories').indexOf(category) >= 0)) {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast')
      }
    })
  });
```

It works perfectly but it seems messy to me. In fact, I've got a lot of functions in my app that look similar. Is there a style guide or something similar to help me refactor this code? How should it be refactored anyway?

I found [this](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/) but I'm not sure where to start with mine.

**EDIT**

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qou974ps/) to illustrate the issue. Essentially the buttons should eliminate "articles" not relevant to the button. It should work like a filter. Presently the fiddle isn't working correctly because I'm halfway through refactoring.

Comment: http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: Hey now, that's a _killer_ resource. Cheers

Comment: just name your functions to get them out of the flow mass and allow recycling, like naming `function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') }` as  `fadeFast`, and calling it from above. if you got rid of all the anons, the code would be quite legible and logical.

Comment: If you're refactoring anyway, might I suggest looking into AngularJS?

Comment: If I'm doing something like `$(this)` all over the place, I like to store the reference in a variable with a proper name, so I can figure out the scope easily.  Also, use semi-colons and maybe use some constants for your CSS properties, like `var CATEGORY_FILTER = '.category-filter'`.

Comment: If you just want suggestions for how to improve this code, then you should probably go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What is your goal when you say "refactor"?

Comment: This code isn't making sense to me.  Won't you be installing duplicate click handlers each time an item is clicked on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to know what could be simplified without understanding what it does, but I would definitely recommend saving off jquery selectors as variables so you don't have to pay the DOM reading cost more than once. People often like to prefix such variables with `$` to indicate that they are jquery objects, but this is really just preference. Also, never underestimate the importance of spacing.

```
var categoryFilter = $('.category-filter');
var articleContainer = $('.article-container');

categoryFilter.click(function() {
  var category = $(this).attr('data-category');

  categoryFilter.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-category').indexOf(category) >= 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success').fadeIn('fast');

      $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-default').fadeIn('fast');
        articleContainer.each(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') })
        categoryFilter.each(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') })
      })
    }
  });

  articleContainer.each(function() {
    if (!($(this).attr('data-categories').indexOf(category) >= 0)) {
      $(this).fadeOut('fast')
    }
  })
});
```

EDIT:

Having looked at this a bit more, I see a couple things you could simplify.

1) As @dandavis mentioned, you can create a named function for your `fadeIn('fast')` calls.

```
function fadeFast() {
  $(this).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

2) You could also create a named function called `swapClass` to handle your `removeClass().addClass()` cases.

```
function swapClass(context, rm, add) {
  return context.removeClass(rm).addClass(add);
}
```

Then invoke it like so:

```
swapClass($(this), 'label-default', 'label-success').fadeIn('fast');
```

But it really feels like that should actually be on the jquery instance (since you have to pass that in as the context), which you can do like this:

```
$.fn.swapClass = function(oldClass, newClass) {
  return this.removeClass(oldClass).addClass(newClass);
};
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
$(this).swapClass('label-default', 'label-success').fadeIn('fast');
```

So that gets you to something like:

```
var categoryFilter = $('.category-filter');
var articleContainer = $('.article-container');

$.fn.swapClass = function(oldClass, newClass) {
  return this.removeClass(oldClass).addClass(newClass);
};

function fadeFast() {
  $(this).fadeIn('fast');
}

categoryFilter.click(function() {
  var category = $(this).attr('data-category');

  categoryFilter.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('data-category').indexOf(category) >= 0) {
      $this.swapClass('label-default', 'label-success').fadeIn('fast');

      $this.click(function() {
        $(this).swapClass('label-success', 'label-default').fadeIn('fast');
        articleContainer.each(fadeFast);
        categoryFilter.each(fadeFast);
      })
    }
  });

  articleContainer.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!($this.attr('data-categories').indexOf(category) >= 0)) {
      $this.fadeOut('fast')
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address what the OP was asking for.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "refactor." I agree, generally. I think the OP is asking about ways to simplify the code, but it's hard to know for sure, without understanding more fully what it does. My point here was just to show that you can make _some_ improvement without actually doing anything at all. For instance, I think it would be much easier to see where to begin real refactoring in my version than in the original, just because of the spacing. Furthermore, it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: there are still a lot of repeats going on. don't be shy, call your functions by name. there's no reason you need the word "function" more than a couple times inside of the click event. ok, you technically don't need it at all, but let's not get carried away: abstracting the boilerplate will be beneficial enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to approach things that creates a class name from the `data-category` attribute to make it easier to select like items with a simple selector:

```
$('.category-filter').each(function() {
    // move data-category attribute to a class name so it's easier to select
    $(this).addClass("cat_" + $(this).data("category"));
}).click(function(e){
    var categoryClass = ".cat_" + $(this).data('category');
    // now change all items with matching category
    $(categoryClass).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success').fadeIn('fast');
          .click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-default');
            $('.article_container').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.category-filter').fadeIn('fast');
          });        
    });
    $('.article_container').not(categoryClass).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

List of Changes:

1. Copy data-category attribute to a class name to make it easier to select all matching category elements.
2. Use chaining in more places to avoid repeating jQuery object creation.
3. Remove some redundant `.fadeIn()` calls.
4. Use the new class name to fadeOut the right articles

I think your code has an issue with installing duplicate click handlers each time a `category-filter` item is clicked on.  I don't quite understand why you're doing it the way you are so I didn't change that part yet.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm showing another way to approach the problem.